# How to make a Gridview Header Check Box

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Using VB.Net (Windows Application)

I am using checkbox in the girdview column, now i want to add a checkbox in the header.

If i select the checkbox in the header, all the checkbox in the column should select automatically.

How to do this.

Need VB.Net Code Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Protected Sub chkbSelectAll_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim chkFlag As Boolean = False
    If chkbSelectAll.Checked Then
        chkFlag = True
    End If
    For Each dr As GridViewRow In gvProducts.Rows
        Dim chk As CheckBox = DirectCast(dr.Cells(0).FindControl("Select"), CheckBox)
        chk.Checked = chkFlag
    Next
End Sub
```

I'm not sure this code is well-written. I just convert from this C# code (which is working);

```
protected void chkbSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool chkFlag = false;
        if (chkbSelectAll.Checked) chkFlag = true;
        foreach (GridViewRow dr in gvProducts.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox chk = (CheckBox)dr.Cells[0].FindControl("Select");
            chk.Checked = chkFlag;
        }
    }
```

Algorithm is simple. Define a boolean value for checking checkboxes are selected or not. If checked assign it true. for all gridview rows, find controls with columns name then set them all.

Answer (score 6):

Add the *first* Checkbox (Handle `CheckedChanged` event and set `AutoPostBack=True`) in `HeaderTemplate` and add  *second* checkbox in `ItemTemplate` of `TemplateField`.

Markup

```
<asp:GridView 
    ID="GridView1" 
    runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="false"
    >
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox 
                ID="CheckBox1" 
                runat="server"
                AutoPostBack="true"
                OnCheckedChanged="CheckUncheckAll"
                />
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" /> 
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <HeaderTemplate>
            Name
        </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal 
                ID="Literal1" 
                runat="server"
                Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'
                >
            </asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Code-Behind

```
  Public Class Data
        Public Property Name As String
    End Class

    Protected Sub CheckUncheckAll(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim chk1 As CheckBox
        chk1 = DirectCast(GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox1"),CheckBox)
        For Each row As GridViewRow In GridView1.Rows
            Dim chk As CheckBox
            chk =DirectCast(row.Cells(0).FindControl("CheckBox2"),CheckBox)
            chk.Checked = chk1.Checked
        Next
    End Sub
    Dim lst As List(Of Data)
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            lst = New List(Of Data)
            lst.Add(New Data() With {.Name = "A"})
            lst.Add(New Data() With {.Name = "B"})
            lst.Add(New Data() With {.Name = "C"})

            GridView1.DataSource = lst
            GridView1.DataBind()
        End If
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Header template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.headertemplate.aspx) in order to render a checkbox. And you will need to some javascript to check all the rows when header checked.